# Measuring data transmissions from your iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, payload, transmission

Just curious if anyone knows how I can measure the data transmission from my iPhone app. A client wants to know what to expect in terms of cost, so we should be able to measure the payload per form and multiply it by the number of expected form transmissions. Does anyone know of a simple tool I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can observe your data usage in the Xcode:
[image: Data usage]

If your want to get the rough data usage, use the application with your typical workload and analysis the usage after that.